# BigInteger logical operation takes more time in subsequent loops C#

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators, biginteger, xor

I have the below console application to check the time taken for doing a specific operation with BigInteger in C#.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Numerics;
 
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loop Started {0}",j);
    timer.Start();
    BigInteger bitFields = 0;
    byte value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 65400; ++i)
    {
        var bb = new BigInteger(value);
        var result = (bb << (i * 8));
        bitFields = bitFields ^ result;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed duration: {0}", timer.Elapsed.ToString());
    timer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Loop Completed");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Even though I expect approximately similar time taken for each loop, the result shows differently. Time to execute the loop increases gradually

[image]

Is there any reason for this behaviour.

Comment: stopwatch is not suitable enough for benchmarking operations like that; use https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: Notwithstanding the benchmarking issues, why would you expect BigInteger operation times to be constant as the size of the BigIntegers gets larger? I would expect these operations to take time approximately linear in the number of bits in the BigInteger. It would take some very advanced optimization to discover that `bb` only has a single *word* of non-zero bits and take advantage of this to achieve constant time performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you start/resume the same timer with [`Stopwatch.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.start?view=net-7.0):

> Starts, **or resumes**, measuring elapsed time for an interval.

You can switch to [`Stopwatch.Restart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.restart?view=net-7.0):

> Stops time interval measurement, resets the elapsed time to zero, and starts measuring elapsed time.

```
for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Loop Started {0}",j);
    timer.Restart();
    // ..
}
```

Also note that for benchmarking it is better to use specialized tools like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).